# ID_FS_LABEL in udev

Tags: usb, udev, devices

What is `ID_FS_LABEL` in udev? Also why doesn't it show up when I execute this command :

```
sudo udevadm info --root --name=/dev/sdb
```

The output that I get for the above command :

```
vineet@vineet:~$ sudo udevadm info --root --name=/dev/sdb
[sudo] password for vineet: 
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0/block/sdb
N: sdb
S: disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_89Y61R3Z86FY3BG7-0:0
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_89Y61R3Z86FY3BG7-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0/block/sdb
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=Transcend_4GB
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Transcend\x204GB\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=1000
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=1100
E: ID_SERIAL=JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_89Y61R3Z86FY3BG7-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=89Y61R3Z86FY3BG7
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=JetFlash
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=JetFlash
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=8564
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=16
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=mbr
E: UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=925775101
```

I am looking for the property that corresponds to the volume label of a usb mass storage device. In my case I was looking for a property that is equal to `UUI`.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Care to mention why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found an answer.

- FS LABEL stands for filesystem label.
- FS LABEL didn't show up for the above command because the DEVTYPE for which it is displayed is **partition** !
- FS LABEL correctly displays the volume label which I verified by executing the above command for /dev/sdb1.